# How to re-arrange my dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, tabular

I have 24 rows of data, and 2820 columns. How can I split this large horizontally table to vertical, cut every 60 column and stack it under each other:

This is a sample pic of 12 col and 6 rows:

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions

Comment: Sorry, I just uploaded some examples to illustrate the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, though I think what you're looking for is the melt() function. This will convert your wide dataset to a long one. That being said, I have no idea what your intentions are, so I'm not sure if the number 60 has any importance.

If melt() is what you want, you can use it by specifying an id variable, suppose its col1, and everything else will automatically become a variable. If your table is named "x":

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  ...
A     22     5    17
B     43     6    54
...

melt(x, id.vars = col1)

col1  variable  value
A     col2      22     
A     col3      5
A     col4      17
...
```

Comment: I don't think wide-long is the problem here. My understanding is that they just want to "slice" into columns 1-60, 61-120...2761-2820 and then essentially `rbind` those slices together.

Comment: This is a dangerous thing to do, unless the columns have no independent meaning in the first place, in which case why aren't they in the same column to begin wiith?

Comment: But I agree that's what it sounds like the op is asking.

Comment: Yes, I want to slice the table. And columns have no independent meaning. I have this table as a dataframe.

Comment: The answer below works for a `data.frame` same like for a `matrix`

Answer (score 0):

Including a reduced example, you could do the following:

```
# sample data
myMat <- matrix(rnorm(24*282), nrow = 24)

myList <- lapply(1:(282/6), function(x) myMat[, (6*(x-1)+1):(6*x)])

myNewMat <- do.call("rbind", args = myList)

dim(myNewMat)
## [1] 1128    6
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @RolandASc's answer would be something like the following:

```
mydf
#   X_1      X_2  X_3 X_4 X_5      X_6  X_7 X_8 X_9     X_10  X_11 X_12
# 1  A1 1/1/2016 2:30   5  D1 1/1/2017 5:30  15  A2 5/1/2016 12:30   50
# 2  B1 1/2/2016 3:30   5  E1 1/2/2017 6:30  25  B2 5/2/2016 13:30  500
# 3  C1 1/3/2016 4:30   8  F1 1/3/2017 7:30  80  C2 5/3/2016 14:30  800

library(data.table)
rbindlist(split.default(mydf, 0:(ncol(mydf)-1) %/% 4))
#    X_1      X_2   X_3 X_4
# 1:  A1 1/1/2016  2:30   5
# 2:  B1 1/2/2016  3:30   5
# 3:  C1 1/3/2016  4:30   8
# 4:  D1 1/1/2017  5:30  15
# 5:  E1 1/2/2017  6:30  25
# 6:  F1 1/3/2017  7:30  80
# 7:  A2 5/1/2016 12:30  50
# 8:  B2 5/2/2016 13:30 500
# 9:  C2 5/3/2016 14:30 800
```

---

To do this every 60 columns for a `data.frame` with 2820 columns, you can use the following to create the split indices:

```
0:(2820-1) %/% 60
```

---

Sample data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  X_1 = c("A1", "B1", "C1"), X_2 = c("1/1/2016", "1/2/2016", "1/3/2016"), 
  X_3 = c("2:30", "3:30", "4:30"), X_4 = c(5, 5, 8), 
  X_5 = c("D1", "E1", "F1"), X_6 = c("1/1/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/3/2017"), 
  X_7 = c("5:30", "6:30", "7:30"), X_8 = c(15, 25, 80), 
  X_9 = c("A2", "B2", "C2"), X_10 = c("5/1/2016", "5/2/2016", "5/3/2016"), 
  X_11 = c("12:30", "13:30", "14:30"), X_12 = c(50, 500, 800)
)
```